# Integrate django via pydev in eclipse?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I have installed eclipse indigo and pydev and python 32.

I have configured my python path and can create an "empty" django project:

[image]

However, when I run right click on project and run as->pydev: django

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\djangoworkspace\test3\src\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\project_template\settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

Any idea what I ned to fix to run a django project in eclipse?

Comment: This post http://lowcoupling.com/post/47845431628/creating-a-new-django-project-with-eclipse-py-dev provides a complete tutorial for it. I hope it could help

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to follow these steps from http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html

> 1. The project must be marked as a Django project inside of PyDev.
> 2. A DJANGO_MANAGE_LOCATION string substitution variable must point to the project-relative location of manage.py.
> 3. A DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE string substitution variable must contain the name of the settings module in that project.

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is actually python module name, not a specific file.  So your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be 'project_template.settings'

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the project and select 'Pydev-Django' and the following

1. 'Django manage.py': this is relative path to the manage.py file with respect to the project root
2. 'Django settings module:' this is python dotted path to the setting file being used (exclude .py) as shown below
   [image]

> if you see the message " Module: x.x.setting could be found" as in the picture above then add
>   this project to the python path as show below

right click the project and select Pydev - PYTHONPATH

[image]

now python project is added

[image]

After adding python path to the project settings module is found
[image]

Everything will fine now :)
note: This was made using django 1.10 and pydev 5.2

Answer (score 4):

- Go to Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python
- Go to the String Substitution Variables tab
- Add the 2 following variables:

  - DJANGO_MANAGE_LOCATION with the path to django/conf/project_template/
  - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE with the /settings/